# Really old URL that redirects to an old URL that redirects to the current URL is still being crawled by Googlebot

Tags: seo, url

I am working on a website and just change to a new template. My boss also decided to change all the URLs.

I did all the redirection in *.htaccess*.  Lets say old URL is `site1.html` which will become `site2.html` (new URL). Also `site1.html` was `site.html` before. Set-up is like this:

- `Redirect 301 /site.html /site1.html`
- `Redirect 301 /site1.html /site2.html` (I added this one)

My problem now is when I check crawl errors in Google Search Console, `site.html` is still being crawled. Should I delete the `Redirect 301 /site.html /site1.html` in the *.htaccess*?

Comment: If you publish content on a URL and get it crawled by Google, Googlebot will come and visit it **forever**.   I have URLs that I removed 15 years ago.   Google still checks them out sometimes.